# Audio driver for HP chromebook 14a-na0216ng on Windows 10

Tags: windows, drivers, chromebook

I wanted to ask where i can find an audio driver for HP Chromebook 14a-na0216ng which is currently reinstalled on Windows.

I found all the other drivers but i can not find an audio one.. The sound card says that it is a Audio by Bang & Olufsen: Dual speakers. I found drivers for B&O but they won't work..

Can someone help me how to resolve the audio problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: anyone? please..

Answer (score 0):

i have **hp chromebook 14a-na0000** installed win10 and download all driver without audio driver can't find it ....please i need solution

**this is spec.**

PROCESSOR
Intel® Celeron® N4020 CPU @ 1.10GHz
GRAPHICS
Intel® UHD Graphics 600
NETWORKING AND I/O
Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
Realtek RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Adapter
MEMORY
4 GB
STORAGE
Kingston TX2964

thanks.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1197588)